# Missing values NaN replace conditional Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, fillna

I have a dataset containing the values of several indicators of a series of countries and years (3072,1134 rows and columns), but some NaN.

Find below a sample of the dataset:

| Year | Country | Submitted | Age12 | Age14 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | CHI | 1 | 267 | 136 | ... |
| 2018 | CHI | 1 | 267 | NaN | ... |
| 2019 | CHI | NaN | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2020 | CHI | 1 | 244 | 203 | ... |
| 2017 | ALB | 1 | 160 | 148 | ... |
| 2018 | ALB | 1 | 163 | 165 | ... |
| 2019 | ALB | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2020 | ALB | 1 | 161 | NaN | ... |
| 2017 | GER | 1 | NaN | 320 | ... |
| 2018 | GER | 1 | 451 | 381 | ... |
| 2019 | GER | NaN | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2020 | GER | 1 | 361 | 321 |  |
| 2017 | BRI | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2018 | BRI | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2019 | BRI | NaN | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2020 | BRI | 1 | 322 | 298 |  |

**I would like to replace missing values based on the values of the column `Submitted`.**

**I would like to change the values by the previous row only if the respective `Submitted` value is "NaN".**

And this is what I would like to have:

| Year | Country | Submitted | Age12 | Age14 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | CHI | 1 | 267 | 136 | ... |
| 2018 | CHI | 1 | 267 | NaN | ... |
| 2019 | CHI | 1 | 267 | NaN | ... |
| 2020 | CHI | 1 | 244 | 203 | ... |
| 2017 | ALB | 1 | 160 | 148 | ... |
| 2018 | ALB | 1 | 163 | 165 | ... |
| 2019 | ALB | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2020 | ALB | 1 | 161 | NaN | ... |
| 2017 | GER | 1 | NaN | 320 | ... |
| 2018 | GER | 1 | 451 | 381 | ... |
| 2019 | GER | 1 | 451 | 381 | ... |
| 2020 | GER | 1 | 361 | 321 | ... |
| 2017 | BRI | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2018 | BRI | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2019 | BRI | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2020 | BRI | 1 | 322 | 298 |  |

With some help from the community, I tried using

```
df = df.where(~df.Sumbitted.isnull(), df.fillna(axis=0, method='ffill'))
```

and

```
df = df.where(~df.Sumbitted.isnull(), df.fillna(axis=0, method='ffill',limit=2))
```

and

```
df = df.where(~df.Sumbitted.isnull(), interpolate(method="pad", limit=2))
```

**However, using these options I get the following instead. The issue is that the code retrieves the previous non-NaN value, but in the cases that the previous value is a NaN the code retrieves the value before the previous until its finds a non-NaN value.**

Output:

| Year | Country | Submitted | Age12 | Age14 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | CHI | 1 | 267 | 136 | ... |
| 2018 | CHI | 1 | 267 | NaN | ... |
| 2019 | CHI | 1 | 267 | 136 | ... |
| 2020 | CHI | 1 | 244 | 203 | ... |
| 2017 | ALB | 1 | 160 | 148 | ... |
| 2018 | ALB | 1 | 163 | 165 | ... |
| 2019 | ALB | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2020 | ALB | 1 | 161 | NaN | ... |
| 2017 | GER | 1 | NaN | 320 | ... |
| 2018 | GER | 1 | 451 | 381 | ... |
| 2019 | GER | 1 | 451 | 381 | ... |
| 2020 | GER | 1 | 361 | 321 |  |
| 2017 | BRI | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2018 | BRI | 1 | NaN | NaN | ... |
| 2019 | BRI | 1 | 361 | 321 | ... |
| 2020 | BRI | 1 | 322 | 298 |  |

See the wrong outputs of CHI 2019 Age14 and BRI Age12 and Age14

Would you know how to solve this issue by fixing this code?
Solutions using a loop or selecting these 2 columns (Age14 and Age12) are not optimal as I have several columns ("..." in the example) and need a systematic solution.

Thank you

Comment: Please explain what criteria you want to filter your data on? do you want to replace null values with other values or delete them?

Comment: @ezzeddin  OP wants to `change the values by the previous row only if the respective "Submitted" value is "NaN".`  See his [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69055417/replace-missing-values-based-on-value-of-a-specific-column-in-python) for more details.   The only difference from the last post is that column `Submitted` also got `NaN` values filled up by previous one row.  That maybe why OP selected that answer (though the answer has different output than the expected output by filling also the `Submitted` column while the expected output was to keep that column unchanged).

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Please consider also upvoting my answer (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter `limit=1` to limit filling only from the previous one row value and not from further up:

```
df = df.where(~df.Submitted.isnull(), df.fillna(axis=0, method='ffill',limit=1))
```

**Or better still, simplify your codes, as follows:**

Use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) instead of [`.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) so that your code don't need extra step to negate the boolean mask.   Also, use [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) which is a simplified form of `.fillna(axis=0, method='ffill')`:

```
df = df.mask(df.Submitted.isna(), df.ffill(limit=1))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

    Year Country  Submitted  Age12  Age14
0   2017     CHI        1.0  267.0  136.0
1   2018     CHI        1.0  267.0    NaN
2   2019     CHI        1.0  267.0    NaN
3   2020     CHI        1.0  244.0  203.0
4   2017     ALB        1.0  160.0  148.0
5   2018     ALB        1.0  163.0  165.0
6   2019     ALB        1.0    NaN    NaN
7   2020     ALB        1.0  161.0    NaN
8   2017     GER        1.0    NaN  320.0
9   2018     GER        1.0  451.0  381.0
10  2019     GER        1.0  451.0  381.0
11  2020     GER        1.0  361.0  321.0
12  2017     BRI        1.0    NaN    NaN
13  2018     BRI        1.0    NaN    NaN
14  2019     BRI        1.0    NaN    NaN
15  2020     BRI        1.0  322.0  298.0
```